# Insert iFrame using jQuery with modal like styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to display my iFrame over the top of an HTML page like a modal. I want to have a transparent background so you can see the original page behind the "iFrame/Modal".

Right now everything is good, except for the background of the iFrame, its not transparent even though I specify that it should be.

I've created a Fiddle to show what's going on: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shkucy5m/1/)

Here is my jQuery

```
if (document.location.pathname === '/account'){
  $(function() {
  $("body").html("<div id='todd' style='position: fixed; overflow: auto; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;>\n" + 
      "<div style='position: fixed; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4); top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; box-sizing: border-box;'></div>\n" +
        "<div style='width: 400px; height: 470px; padding: 0px; background: transparent; margin: auto; max-width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); box-sizing: border-box;'>\n" +
          "<iframe onload='this.style.visibility='visible'' allowtransparency='true' style='visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; background: transparent;' src='https://test-4658.myshopify.com/apps/proxy/credit'></iframe>\n" +
        "</div>\n" +
    "</div>");
  });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: in the fiddle, is there suppose to be an iframe modal that pops open?

Comment: well the jQuery pops it up for you, but you should be able to see the "Hi" behind it, but you can't

Comment: The iframe itself is transparent.  The page you are loading into is not.  It has a white background.  If you inspect and change the background color of the body to transparent (e.g `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)`) you can see through it.

Comment: Hmm, I did and I still can't see behind the iframe..

Comment: Lol ok my bad....  In your script - you are replacing the content of <H1> with the iframe.  There is no "hi" anymore.  Also, you are missing at least one closing tag on the first div.  Double check that html and append the iframe *after* the h1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script you are replacing the content of the body with the iframe.  You should either append it to the body, or you can add another div to put the iframe in.

[See the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/shkucy5m/7/)

```js
 $(function() {
     $("#iframediv").html("<div id='todd' style='position: fixed; overflow: auto; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;>\n" + 
          "<div style='position: fixed; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4); top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; box-sizing: border-box;'></div>\n" +
            "<div style='width: 400px; height: 470px; padding: 0px; background: transparent; margin: auto; max-width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); box-sizing: border-box;'>\n" +
              "<iframe onload='this.style.visibility='visible'' allowtransparency='true' style='visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; background: transparent;' src='https://test-4658.myshopify.com/apps/proxy/credit'></iframe>\n" +
            "</div>\n" +
        "</div>");
  });
```

```html
<h1>
Hi
</h1>
<div id="iframediv">
</div>
```